# How do I suppress "Yellow Text" from Exchange Set-Mailbox, when -WarningAction doesn't seem to work?

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell, logging, remoting

I am doing a bulk import, setting or updating attribute6 on 1,000 users in AD.

I'm using the following Exchange commandlet to accomplish this:

```
 [PS] C:\>set-mailbox -Identity  user@company.com   -CustomAttribute6  knruiz@nfp.com    -WarningAction:SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

The above command is repeated 1000 times and is auto generated.

My problem is that I want to generate a list of errors that I can feed back upstream to resolve errors such as:

- Missing user
- Ambiguous user
- Failure in setting attribute.

What I want to eliminate is the following text:

> WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of 'company.com/Enterprise/Users/last, first' have been
>   modified.

What I've tried was setting the following `-WarningAction:SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

It seems that either the exchange commandlets don't support this, or perhaps because Exchange Powershell commandlets use "remoting" with stubs may be complicating the error handling.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the warning action before running the command:

```
$oldWarningPreference = $WarningPreference
$WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
set-mailbox -Identity  user@company.com -CustomAttribute6 knruiz@nfp.com -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$WarningPreference = $oldWarningPreference
```

Answer (score 0):

Restart your shell session, your command should work as you expect. You could try *-ErrorAction 0* and *-WarningAction 0* but these are just aliases.

Comment: I attempted this in a new Powershell session.  It did not work.

Comment: this should work.. are you using `new-pssession/import-session` to establish connectivity?